# Generic way to set particular parameters of a polymorphic member variable

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Sorry for the convoluted title of my question, conceptually it is quite simple but I can't find any good design to do it.

I have a base class accessible by the end user :

```
class A {
private:
    // m is a functor
    Base* m;
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual void someInterface();
};

class DerivedT1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void someInterface()
    {
        some_parameter++;
    }
private:
    int some_parameter; // how to set?
};

class DerivedT2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void someInterface()
    {
        some_other_parameter += a_third_parameter;
    }
private:
    double some_other_parameter; // how to set?
    double a_third_parameter; // how to set?
};
```

And I am trying to find the most generic way to set `some_parameter` and `some_other_parameter` from `A`'s public interface.

I have thought of giving a number to my parameters but this sounds *really* ugly.

Is there any beautiful, object-oriented way to do this ?

Comment: Doesn't `m->someInterface();` already achieve that? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I really need specific getters and setters for some_parameter and some_other_parameter.
someInterface() is in fact an algorithm that uses different "kind" of parameters, but to achieve the same goal (if you are interested it is noise reduction algorithm)

Comment: So, you have two different classes, that have different member variables, and you want to have a common way to set those values?

Comment: And how do you know which one to set to what value? [I mean from the code that uses `A`]

Comment: Well, right now I put all my parameters in A and I have a ton of getters and setters in A. I would like the getters and setters to correspond more closely to the class they are working with.

Comment: For instance, one idea I thought of was to have the user of A instantiate `A::m` first with `DerivedT1`, i.e. `DerivedT1 *x = new DerivedT1; x->setSomeParam(10); A.setm(x);` but this is clumsy if you want to do `x->setSomeParam(50)` after.

Comment: And the other would be to keep my shitload of setters in A, and since A knows the type of m with an enum, only call the derived classes methods from A's methods if the type is correct. But this is ugly, too, I think.

Comment: You have to try to somehow abstract those parameters away and represent them in a uniform way in `Base` (e.g., using a method like `setParametersFromString(string)`). If `A` has to know which kind of `Base` it is working with, then `Base` obviously isn't a good abstraction.

Comment: And how would a desirable call from `A` look like?

Comment: It is numerical parameters for scientific algorithms so there is absolutely no abstraction I can think of :/

Comment: Maybe `A` doesn't need to set them. Could they be set in the constructors of the two `Derived` classes?

Comment: I would have liked to do something like `A a; a.setAlgorithmFamily(Algorithm::Type1); a.getAlgorithmImplementation().setSomeParameter(34);`

Comment: Ah, I see. Then minicaptain's answer is probably the best: Move the `Base` construction out of `A`. And maybe create a factory for algortihm implementations.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt : they can change after construction, for instance if I have to do multiple calls with different parameters.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt how do you make a factory ? I always see the "factory object" term but I never found a good explanation / link.

Comment: A factory is just an object that provides convenience methods for constructing other object. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use A's public interface to set derived class parameters:
you can define a public function In A, which have a Base* parameter:

```
class A
{
public:
void setter(const Base *p);
{
     m = p;
}
};
```

if you want to set `Drived1` you can define a object of `Derived1`, can pass it to setter;
I think you want to pass value using A's public function, you must know the type of pointer of `Base*`,so you can pass value by the constructor of `Derived1` or `Derived2`!

Comment: Okay, I'll try to implement this way!

Answer (score 1):

I nothing else works, you could always use a dynamic cast:

```
DerivedT1 *d1 = dynamic_cast<DerivedT1>(m);
if (d1 != nullptr)
{
    // do something with derived 1
}
else
{
    DerivedT2 *d2 = dynamic_cast<DerivedT2>(m);
    if (d2 != nullptr)
    {
        // do something with derived 2
    }
}
```

But if you need that, it's usually a sign that there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it but I try to avoid it as much as I can.

Comment: But I didn't know that dynamic_cast would return nullptr if the type is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something along these lines

```
A a; a.setAlgorithmFamily(Algorithm::Type1);
a.getAlgorithmImplementation().setSomeParameter(34);
```

This is a quick and kind of dirty example of how you could do it. A::setAlgorithmType is basically a factory pattern in it's simplest form.

```
nclude <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Algorithm {
public:
   virtual void setParameter(int value) = 0;
};
class AlgoX : public Algorithm {
   int mX;
public:
   void setParameter(int value) {
      cout <<"Setting X to " <<value <<endl;
      mX = value;
   }
};
class AlgoY : public Algorithm {
   int mY;
public:
   void setParameter(int value) {
      cout <<"Setting Y to " <<value <<endl;
      mY = value;
   }
};
class A {
public:
   void setAlgorithmType(std::string type) {
      cout <<"Now using algorithm " <<type <<endl;
      if(type == "X")
         mAlgorithm = new AlgoX();
      else if(type == "Y")
         mAlgorithm = new AlgoY();
   }
   Algorithm* getAlgorithmImplementation() { return mAlgorithm; }
private:
   Algorithm* mAlgorithm;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   A a;
   a.setAlgorithmType("X");
   a.getAlgorithmImplementation()->setParameter(5);
   return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
Now using algorithm X
Setting X to 5
```

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that the different algorithms have :
* different kinds of parameters
* different number of parameters

But! Some alogrithms also share some parameters becase they are "modified" versions of others, but not all of them, or they add parameters upon other algorithms. (sorry for ugly comment, it's hard without identation!)